# Load content from a div on another page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Trying to load content to a div `#load-here`, from specific div `.date-outer` on another page on click.

**HTML**

```
<button class='btn'/>
<div id="load-here"></div> <!-- Load Here -->

</body>
```

*HTML Structure of external site:*

```
<body>
<div class="blog-posts hfeed"> 

<div class="date-outer">
Contecnt 1</div>

<div class="date-outer">
Contecnt 2</div>

<div class="date-outer">
Contecnt 3</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Means, when click button `.btn` data will load from given link, when click again data will load from second div. Example below:

*On first click*

```
 <body>    
 <button class='btn'/>
<div id="load-here">
 <div class="date-outer"> <!--Loaded Data-->
   Contecnt 1</div>
</div>
<body>
```

*On second click*

```
 <body>    
 <button class='btn'/>
<div id="load-here">
 <div class="date-outer"> <!--Loaded Data-->
   Contecnt 1</div>

 <div class="date-outer"> <!--Loaded Data-->
   Contecnt 2</div>

</div>
<body>
```

*On third click*

```
 <body>    
 <button class='btn'/>
<div id="load-here">
 <div class="date-outer"> <!--Loaded Data-->
   Contecnt 1</div>
 <div class="date-outer"> <!--Loaded Data-->
   Contecnt 2</div>
 <div class="date-outer"> <!--Loaded Data-->
   Contecnt 3</div>
</div>
<body>
```

Means want to load data form external site/link on click, how to do this by Jquery/ajax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook the click event of the given button to a function, then load the content from the other site if not done yet. Once you've got the content, you can simply query that html for `.data-outer` and copy the contents from the next one those `div`s you want to target to the real page.

```
$(function() {
    var page = null;
    var counter = 0;

    function getNext() {
        // Grab the next element from the array of date-outer divs and copy it to the .content div
        if (counter >= page.length)
            return;
        var elm = $(page[counter]).clone();
        elm.find('script').remove(); // Remove script tags in the div
        elm.appendTo('#load-here');
        counter++;
    }

    $('.btn').click(function(e) {
        if (page === null) {
            page = false; // Prevents the request from being made twice
            $.get('http://....com/../', function(data) {
                page = $(data).find('.date-outer');
                getNext();
            });
        } else if (page !== false) {
            getNext();
        }
    });
});
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hpu5f4ur/ (note: **requires** http and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` due to the example site not allowing https and Jsfiddle not setting this header by default).

Comment: Hi, my question Edited, please change `.content` to `#load-here`. please refresh this page and see the change of my question.

Comment: Hi thanks, but not working please see example here: http://test-html-site.blogspot.com/    # what i doing wrong? You may see HTml source by Inspect-element on chrome.

Comment: Use the recently edited code, the one you currently use had a small error.

Comment: Please see this here:  http://test-html-site.blogspot.com/ ( funny things) i have used `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: It's probably caused by the scripts those divs contain, try my edited answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90171/discussion-between-aabira-and-tgys).